# Fail to make DML or send emails from License Trigger

Tags: trigger, error, licenses, lma

We are having a problem when the LMA process updates a license that we are not able to figure out.
We have an after update/insert trigger on sfLma__License__c which among other things updates Accounts and sends Emails, and the moment we make the DML or send the email we get the following error:

**Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0010c00001yUpg8AAC; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, Failed to publish events: []**

AND

**SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, Failed to publish events: []**

We don't have any Platform Events defined in our org.